# Extract required elements from list and make another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following list, out of which I want to extract only names and make another list. Can someone help me in achieving this?

```
>>> a = [{'name': 'mytestbuild', 'notes': 'Autocreated build.', 'testplan_id': '178775', 'closed_on_date': '', 'release_date': '', 'is_open': '1', 'active': '1', 'creation_ts': '2017-05-09 11:20:25', 'id': '160'}, {'name': 'mytestbuild_delete', 'notes': 'Autocreated build.', 'testplan_id': '178775', 'closed_on_date': '', 'release_date': '', 'is_open': '1', 'active': '1', 'creation_ts': '2017-05-18 15:24:37', 'id': '164'}]
```

From this, I want to get the list of only 'name', i.e.,

```
name_list = ['mytestbuild', 'mytestbuild_delete']
```

This doesn't work:

```
>>> a['name']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `name_list = [item['name'] for item in a]`

Comment: Can you please post it as answer, I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing

```
print (a[0]['name'])
```

This will print

```
mytestbuild
```

And to make it into a list

```
lis= [m['name'] for m in a]
print (lis)
```

This will print the list

```
['mytestbuild', 'mytestbuild_delete']
```